# Crash Emacs on M1 mac from Electron

Tags: macos, emacs, electron, homebrew, apple-m1

On 'Electron', when I try to exec Emacs
on new M1 mac by using child_process.exec('Emacs'),
the process is crashed and the report attached below is given.
On the old mac, it works.
The code is as follows:

> exec(`/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "{$ExecPathEscape(dirPath)}"' ...

How can I fix it?

'Emacs' was installed by 'brew install cask emacs'
and
'Electron' was installed by 'npm install electron'.

```sh
> node --version
v16.11.0
> emacs --version
GNU Emacs 27.2
```

```
Process:               Emacs-x86_64-10_14 [28673]
Path:                  /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_14
Identifier:            org.gnu.Emacs
Version:               Version 27.2 (9.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        org_viewer_for_electron [28667]
Responsible:           org_viewer_for_electron [28667]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-10-16 14:52:14.719 +0900
OS Version:            macOS 11.6 (20G165)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        85EA4D90-AA61-E019-08A5-82B0FB446187

Sleep/Wake UUID:       E05F8F97-4CFE-4F3E-A8EB-88E278C78BE3

Time Awake Since Boot: 22000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       210 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             0x00007ffe946828f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2042392e __pthread_kill + 10
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff20336bd5 raise + 26
3   Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001023db6d9 terminate_due_to_signal + 153
4   Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001023dc01b emacs_abort + 15
5   Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001023a3880 ns_term_shutdown + 80
6   Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001022935d4 shut_down_emacs + 340
7   Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001023db6a6 terminate_due_to_signal + 102
8   Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001022b3e8e handle_fatal_signal + 14
9   Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001022b3f11 deliver_thread_signal + 129
10  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001022b2969 deliver_fatal_thread_signal + 9
11  libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff20497d7d _sigtramp + 29
12  ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
13  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001023785c9 decode_time_components + 633
14  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001023790df decode_lisp_time + 159
15  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010237a240 Ftime_convert + 32
16  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102320331 funcall_subr + 257
17  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f91b Ffuncall + 843
18  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
19  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
20  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
21  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
22  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
23  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
24  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
25  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
26  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
27  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
28  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
29  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
30  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
31  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
32  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231ff8c call1 + 44
33  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010232b4c8 mapcar1 + 88
34  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010232b90b Fmapc + 75
35  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102320331 funcall_subr + 257
36  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f91b Ffuncall + 843
37  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
38  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f8b9 Ffuncall + 745
39  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102362c57 exec_byte_code + 1815
40  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231f164 apply_lambda + 356
41  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231b69f eval_sub + 783
42  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231ee9a Feval + 106
43  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231df77 internal_condition_case + 263
44  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001022a772d top_level_1 + 45
45  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010231d79b internal_catch + 267
46  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001023dba96 command_loop.cold.1 + 54
47  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102296633 command_loop + 131
48  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x0000000102296563 recursive_edit_1 + 115
49  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x00000001022967bb Frecursive_edit + 347
50  Emacs-x86_64-10_14              0x000000010229534c main + 7436
51  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2046df3d start + 1

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdfff96a28 0x7ffdfff92000 + 18984
1   runtime                         0x00007ffdfff9beec 0x7ffdfff92000 + 40684
2   runtime                         0x00007ffdfff9d2c0 0x7ffdfff92000 + 45760

Thread 2:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdfffb47c8 0x7ffdfff92000 + 141256

Thread 3:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdfffb47c8 0x7ffdfff92000 + 141256

Thread 4:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdfffb47c8 0x7ffdfff92000 + 141256

Thread 5:
0   runtime                         0x00007ffdfffb47c8 0x7ffdfff92000 + 141256

Thread 6:
0   ???                             0x00007ffe946828f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff20425656 __select + 10
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff211fd437 __NSThread__start__ + 1068
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff204528fc _pthread_start + 224
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2044e443 thread_start + 15

Thread 7:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   ???                             0x00007ffe946828f4 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff2041d2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2054b215 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff205498cb __CFRunLoopRun + 1332
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20548cd0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e0223a _NSEventThread + 124
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff204528fc _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2044e443 thread_start + 15

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
 rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000202d57e00  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
 rdi: 0x0000000000000004  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x0000000000000003  rsp: 0x00000000000001ad
  r8: 0x0000000000000006   r9: 0x0000000000000003  r10: 0x0000000202d57e00  r11: 0x00007fff20336bbb
 r12: 0x0000000000000103  r13: 0x0000000000000002  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
 rip: <unavailable>  rfl: 0x0000000000000283
```

Answer (score 0):

We've solved it by ourselves.
When we directly symlink the arm64 of Emacs, bin, and libexe,
it works.

```
> pwd
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS
> rm bin
> ln -s bin-arm64-11_2/ bin
> rm libexec
> ln -s lib-arm64-11_2/ libexec
> mv Emacs Emacs-orig
> ln -s Emacs-arm64-11_2 Emacs
```

In the original Emacs script provided by Homebrew,
the checking of architecture was done by

```
> uname -m
arm64
```

and returns the appropriate answer,
but the executed version was x86_64.
We can't propose the revised solution of Emacs, but it works.

Comment: We've now reached that the crash was due to the 'Electron' architecture. When we change the 'Electron' from x86_64 to universal version, 'uname -m' returns appropriate answer. The original Emacs runs well.